# Spin of an electron

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-spin, quantum-electrodynamics, electrons

I have a conceptual difficulty in understanding the electron spin. On the one hand, it is an experimental, observable feature of electrons. The problem is in understanding to what it belongs - to a bare electron or to an electron already coupled to the electromagnetic field. I think it is the latter. In other words, the electron spin characterizes a complicated object (a real system) rather than a "free" (non interacting) electron. It is like the total spin of a compound system. On the other hand, in theory we ascribe it to a "bare" electron solely. Do you think we have a conceptual problem here?

Comment: Yes, there could be a conceptual problem. But as far as I know there is no other behaviour known from any experiment so it might indeed be that we can assume the electron to be described in the sense we know.

Answer (score 3):

There is no conceptual problem. The bare electron field is a Dirac, spin-1/2 field, and so is the renormalized field. A bare electron carries $j=1/2$, and so does the physical, renormalized electron.

In fact, because spin is a discrete quantum number, a continuous process such as renormalization (a process that depends either on a continuous coupling $e$ or the mass scale $\mu$) couldn't change the value of such a quantum number.

So the equal value of both spins is not only free of contradictions; it is inevitable.

Comment: Hi Lubosh, I am glad that you admit that the spin 1/2 belongs to the real, renormalized, dressed electron. This is what I would like to underline: it is a spin of a compound system. It is not so evident. You know, an atom, as a compound system, may have the the angular momentum 1/2 but it is not obligatory. A compound system may have different total angular momenta. Besides, your argument about discreteness of quantum number is not convincing. First, there is no explicit solution for a renormalized electron to judge. Next, renormalizations change nothing by definition, not only spin.